# Add Timestamp to file name during saving Data Frame in csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests, export-to-csv

When I save a file to .csv I want to add next to it the timestamp when that file was created. I tried this one but it didnt work:

```
df.to_csv('File_name_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
```

It is giving me this output:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'File_name_2021-05-12 16:20:23.csv'
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: This might have to do with your operating system not allowing the ":" character (windows doesn't allow that) try to think of a different way displaying it (eg with - or _)

Comment: Thansk a lot, it worked, just removed the ":".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colons are not permitted in filenames on Windows, so you can use your line sans-colons and it should work fine:

```py
df.to_csv('File_name_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")))
```

### Per Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions):

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
> Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
> (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - < (less than)
>   - > (greater than)
>   - : (colon)
>   - " (double quote)
>   - / (forward slash)
>   - \ (backslash)
>   - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - ? (question mark)
>   - * (asterisk)
> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>   are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
>   Streams.
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way around this could be to do the following:

```
df.to_csv('File_name_{}.csv'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %Hh%Mm%Ss")))
```